# Install NVidia drivers from .run provided by geforce.com

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I am currently using the Nvidia 319 drivers provided by Ubuntu repos, but I want to use the 331 driver. The problem is the Xorg Edgers ppa I used to rely on offers a broken 331 driver (installs bumblebee, blacklisting the nvidia driver).

I downloaded the driver provided by the website geforce.com for my NVidia GTX 760 as a .run file, but I don't know if the procedure I'm thinking about is correct:

1. Command line boot
2. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`
3. `sudo ./driver.run`

Is this procedure correct?

Comment: Visit here:http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-the-Latest-NVIDIA-331-20-Drivers-in-Ubuntu-13-10-399182.shtml and scroll down to the second method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to switch to non graphical tty suppose tty1 <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

login with username and password

stop lightdm:

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

remove the old nvidia driver

```
sudo apt-get purge ^nvidia
```

Give execute permission to the .run file driver

```
sudo chmod +x driver.run
```

Now run the script

```
sudo ./driver.run
```

then reboot and the system should now be using the new driver